# Default Latex Classes seen by emacs

Tags: org-mode, latex, ielm

I am trying to write a project proposal by using org-mode. And when I change the #+LATEX_CLASS variable to something different org can not export to pdf.

So, I wondered how can see list of latex classes that are seen by emacs in ielm ?

B.R.

Comment: Could you provide some information on what 'ielm' is? Normally you can see the latex classes org mode knows about by `C-h v org-latex-classes`

Comment: ielm is the repl for emacs-lisp like in the python. I didn't know that we can query commands by pressing C-h v. But still I do not see org-latex-classes. I am using org-mode 9.1.5 (If you want to see ielm => M-x ielm)

Comment: OK, thanks. If I open `ielm` and just type `org-latex-classes` it gives me the list I would expect. What do you get?

Comment: I get nothing! :(

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'nothing'. If the variable is undefined, then something is wrong with the way org-mode is getting set up. If the variable is defined but empty, then you need to define something, as shown in the manual.

Comment: In my case,  i don't see variable named `org-latex-classes`. But I can generate pdfs with org-mode.